# Finding if a path exists between two Nodes in a Graph using Depth First Search(DFS) C++

Tags: c++, recursion, graph, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I'm trying to implement the Depth First Search(DFS) suing recursion to return a boolean value if a path exists between two Nodes in a graph. Below is my implementation. The edges input is in the form of a Vector array.

I tried debugging the program to detect where exactly I am going wrong, but I don't know why it gives a segmentation fault as soon as I call `return validPath_helper(n, i, destination, visited, adjList);` function in the `validPath` function after checking if the Node is visited or not.

```cpp
bool validPath_helper(int n, int source, int destination, vector<bool> visited, vector<vector<int>> adjList){
    visited[source] = true;

    if(adjList[source][destination]){
        return true;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<adjList[source].size(); i++){
        if(adjList[source][i]){
            return validPath_helper(n, i, destination, visited, adjList);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool validPath(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, int source, int destination) {
    vector<bool> visited(n, false);
    vector<vector<int>> adjList(n);

    int u, v;
    for(int i=0; i<edges.size(); i++){
        u = edges[i][0];
        v = edges[i][1];
        adjList[u].push_back(v);
        adjList[v].push_back(u);
    }

    for(int i=source; i<n; i++){
        if(!visited[i]){
            return validPath_helper(n, i, destination, visited, adjList);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: lets use adjList.at(i) instead of adjList[i], it'll throw some exception when you access a  element which is outbound of adjList

Comment: Can you clarify the format of your nodes ? Are they integers in range 0 to N-1 or something else ?

Comment: Extract a [mcve] and include that in your question. Also, run the code in a debugger to step through it. Set a breakpoint on the line before the error.

Comment: Yep, the nodes are integers in range from 0 to N-1 @PragunSaini

Comment: I did run the code in a debugger multiple times @UlrichEckhardt but the problem as stated in the question was that it gave a segmentation fault at the line where I call the `validPath_helper` It's not even entering the helper function. I have no idea why this is so. . .

Comment: Then you should have a backtrace, so add that to your question. Also, the [mcve] is mandatory! Further, most C++ implementations have a diagnostic mode, where containers like `vector` perform checks against some errors that otherwise just incur "undefined behaviour". In particular, that is the checking of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seg faults usually occur due to access of un-allocated memory so that's what you should investigate first. You said that the `validPath_helper` is triggering the seg fault, so you should check that function.

In your case the culprit is this line :

```
if(adjList[source][destination]){
    return true;
}
```

Here you wanted to check that whether there is an edge between source node and destination node. But if you check back to how you created your adjacency list, you will see it is a vector of vectors that is for every node we have a list of nodes it has edges to.

For example the following graph:

```
1 - 2
0 - 1
1 - 3
```

The adjacency list will be :

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 0 2 3
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
```

Let's take source 2 and destination 3.
Now when your `validPath_helper` is called it will check `adjList[2][3]` but as you see above length of adjList[2] is only 1 so there is no 4th element to check (3 is index so 4th element). This is the cause of your seg fault.

This also leads to an entirely different problem in your code that you want to check whether edge exists between 2 and 3 but instead you check whether there is a non-zero element at 4th position of 2's list.

You can fix this a couple of ways.

#### Way # 1

Instead of

```
if(adjList[source][destination]){
    return true;
}
```

try

```
for (int index = 0; index < adjList[source].size(); index++) {
    if (adjList[source][index] == destination)
        return true;
}
```

You need to make this change in both the places of your `validPath_helper` function.

#### Way # 2

The above method increases the runtime of your program in case of big graphs, if you are concerned about runtime and know about hashlists this method is better.

```
#include <unordered_set> // at top

bool validPath_helper(int n, int source, int destination, vector<bool> visited, vector<unordered_set<int>> adjList){
    visited[source] = true;

    if(adjList[source].find(destination) != adjList[source].end()){
        return true;
    }

    for(int i: adjList[source]){
        if (!visited[i] && validPath_helper(n, i, destination, visited, adjList)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool validPath(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, int source, int destination) {
    vector<bool> visited(n, false);
    vector<unordered_set<int>> adjList(n); 

    int u, v;
    for(int i=0; i<edges.size(); i++){
        u = edges[i][0];
        v = edges[i][1];
        adjList[u].insert(v); 
        adjList[v].insert(u);
    }

    return validPath_helper(n, i, destination, visited, adjList);
}
```

There were a couple more bugs in your code :

1. Some unnecessary loops in both your functions.
2. You set visited to true but do not check it before calling DFS on new nodes.
3. You return the first DFS result and don't check other child nodes. (Due to return validPath_helper call in validPath_helper function.

Look into these issues too, refer to way # 2 above if you are stuck.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That helped a lot. Really neat explanation, was stuck on this for a while now and didn't realize where I was going wrong, thanks again!